# two different definitions of a tangent plane are equivalent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, tangent-line, tangent-spaces

I'm reading about tangent planes and have seen two different definitions. Is there a way to show they are equivalent?

[image]

At the very least is there a way to show that the second definition is equivalent to the plane (involving 2-dimensions)

$z = z_0 + f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$ for which i presume the first definition is a generalisation, is that correct?

Comment: How do you define the tangent line to a curve?

Comment: regardless of which definition you choose can you show they are equivalent?